# using jquery to remove a script function from external page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am loading a Page using a coldfusion script to load an external page in the container tag..

Now that page is coming with a sort function like this: `function sorting(sortid)`. Now this function has its own criteria of sorting, like it is always hitting external site for sorting and giving me an error.

as i do not have control over its functionality, i though of rewritting this function on my side and removing the script from their page when i call it, because i am parsing that html, so i can remove the code.

i wan to know how can i remove that function using jquery in external page and i am adding the same script through my code

only thing is i now need to remove the external `script` tag. it is not in head section, it is inside the body element, also there are other scripts, which i do not want to remove.. only this script

I hope there might be some way

i am looking into this

```
$("#container").html(data).removeAttr('script'); - But this will remove all script tags
```

Comment: why don't you try to put the script that you want to remove in a Div and use the ID or CLASS of that div in your jQuery to remove it and its content?

Comment: i can't, it is coming from external page where i have no control, i am just modifying the page as much as i can

Comment: then you need to use PHP CURL if you have no control over the external page and add your scripts to the PHP CURL page... CULR would allow you  to sort data/information before they are displayed on YOUR PAGE.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select by the src attribute if you know the file you wish to remove. `$('#container').html (data).find('script [src="foo.js"]').remove ()`

If you know the order of scripts you could do `$('#container').html (data).find('script').eq(n).remove ()` where n is the index of the script in the selection. Or you could choose to overwrite that function to do nothing.

Comment: but that is not the external file, it is function which starts as function sort(sortid)